# How can I schedule a function that will execute (to perform an API call) even if the app is running in the background or not at all.

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

So our app makes use of UILocalNotifications which are scheduled for every morning at 9am. The content of this message is dependant on an API call which I want to make 5 minutes before the notification is scheduled for.

So for example, the notification might be set to remind the user to do task x, but there is the chance that the user has already task x (via the online portal and not app), in which case we want to tell them to do task Y instead. For various reasons we don't have a push notification server set up yet but will soon, so this is an interim solution fo rhte purpose of testing.

So my question is: How can I schedule an API call to be made which replaces the immiment notification message depending on the response, even if the app is in the background, or even closed?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a silent local notification that you handle in the AppDelegate when it fires.

Comment: Short answer; you can't. There is no way to schedule your app to execute at a specific time on iOS.

Comment: @Callam, so is this basically schedulling a regular UILocalNotification but without assigning a category or send message to it, so that it 'fires' but does not show a notification banner on the phone? And if so, do I then handle it in 'didReceiveLocalNotification'?

Comment: There's no real way to send silent notifications, however there are some work arounds. Let me get back to you with one, it could help me out too

Comment: This is possible if you setup with silent push notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use silent push notification. in payload you can have get various information from server. then schedule `UILocalNotification` at 9:00 AM.

When you are using silent push notification your app will invoke in background / terminated state ( Note - would not come foreground ) upto your `UILocalNotification` sound file plays ( max 30 seconds ), in this 30 seconds you can do API related work.

When `UILocalNotification` display in notification center, For example there are 2 buttons with notification "Accepted task" and "Later". So when you tap on though buttons even your app will invoke in background / terminated state, even you can open app and redirect to specific view controller. with both case you can do API related work.

If you keep your `UILocalNotification` object in `NSUserDefault` then you can also retrieve it on `didFinishLaunchingWithOption`, in case your device is restarted and `UILocalNotification` and further API work is very crucial.

Let me know you need any help for silent push notification, `UILocalNotification`, `didFinishLaunchingWithOption` or anything.

**Referral note**

https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/ios8-apps-and-pushkit/

https://developer.apple.com/reference/pushkit

**Source** https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification

Push kit implementation code

import UIKit
import PushKit

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,PKPushRegistryDelegate{

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


    let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
    application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)

    self. PushKitRegistration()

    return true
}



//MARK: - PushKitRegistration

func PushKitRegistration()
{

    let mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue()
    // Create a push registry object
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {

        let voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: mainQueue)

        // Set the registry's delegate to self

        voipRegistry.delegate = self

        // Set the push type to VoIP

        voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushTypeVoIP]

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }


}


@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didUpdatePushCredentials credentials: PKPushCredentials!, forType type: String!) {
    // Register VoIP push token (a property of PKPushCredentials) with server

    let hexString : String = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer(credentials.token.bytes),
        count: credentials.token.length).map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joinWithSeparator("")

    print(hexString)


}


@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload!, forType type: String!) {
    // Process the received push
    // From here you can schedule UILocalNotification

}

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you recommend any tutorials for silent push notifications?

Comment: Thank you for the time @Hasya. I have a question still, what is the reason for the references to VoIP?

Comment: To remove dependency of getting data from API and use that data on UILocalNotification. even that would not invoke your app in background and you would not be able to do further things like passing data in API. So using PushKit you can do all this things in manner and your things will be achievable.Contact me if you need any further guidance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this 'dependency of getting data from the API'? In what sort of situation would this dependency be in place? How does it being a VoIP push type remove this dependency over other types? Thanks for bearing with me, I just want to understand 100% :)